# Asking "No?" as in "Really?" after a statement

Tags: grammar

Fore example:

> Person 1: I can't believe its almost Christmas!
>
> Person 2: No?

Does that response mean approximately the same thing as if you used "Really?" in the same place?

> Person 1: I can't believe its almost Christmas!
>
> Person 2: Really?

Or "Why?"

> Person 1: I can't believe its almost Christmas!
>
> Person 2: Why?

Comment: I would elaborate that as, “No? You can’t believe it?” and would roughly equate that with “*Really?*” as you suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is it all depends.

Is Person 2 agreeing, disagreeing, surprised, puzzled, alarmed or reacting in some other way to what Person 1 is saying?

Person 2's responses might be any of the following:

> No, you're right. (Meaning "yes you're right")
>
> No? Why do you say that?
>
> Yes, it does seem to have arrived suddenly.
>
> Why has it taken you by surprise?
>
> Really, you surprise me! We've been making preparations for ages.

There is no correct or best answer to your question. It all depends on the context.

Comment: The context and more importantly the tone of the response.

Comment: The question mark OP gives rules out most of these.